# cmake remove previously added TARGET_COMPILE_OPTIONS

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

I have a cmake project that is part of some larger environment.

There are some cmake makros/functions that I have to use to set up my project.

At some point they add a compile flag:

```
TARGET_COMPILE_OPTIONS (${name} PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:/GL>")
```

however, i want to remove this flag afterwards because it causes some inconvenience in my project.

But there seems to be a bug in cmake:

I tried to to remove the flags from the `INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS` and `COMPILE_OPTIONS` (this is there `target_compile_options` adds the options according to [cmake doku](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_options.html) ).
`message` commands before and after the removal shows the success but the generated `vcxproj` file still contains the

```
  <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
```

in the `<ItemDefinitionGroup><ClCompile>`  section.
So it seems that adding the `/GL` flags triggers some internal state change that can not be removed afterwards. (if i remove the addition of that flag in the macro I have to call, then the `WholeProgramOptimization` node is not added to the vcxproj)

Did I miss something?

I can just add a `/GL-` as an option but then I get a lot of `D9025` warnings (override /GL with /GL-)

(tested with cmake 3.15 and 3.13)

Comment: Please, provide **more code**. It would be nice to see [mcve] which reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that the problem is that the cmake scripts I have to use sets the optimizer settings with `PUBLIC` as scope

```
TARGET_COMPILE_OPTIONS (${name} PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:/GL>")`
                                ^^^^^^
```

Another dependency of my project uses the same function and gets this flag into its `INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS` and my project inherits this option without possibility to remove it.

The only way seems to be to get the common scripts fixed to use `PRIVATE` scope instead. This would be more logical, since its an internal target property that does not have any implications to the consumer.